# Using swiftmailer in a repository class

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to send email in a repository class in symfony2 but I get this error:

Error:

```
Undefined method 'get'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

the code is :

```
public function sendMail()
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('info@test.com')
        ->setBody("Salam dadash kheili khosh omadi");
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

what should I change or do?
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good idea to do it from repository class. It should be moved to some service and called as an event or in the simplest way - from Controller. The repository class really do only database things.

In your case the issue is in $this->get('mailer'), because you are in repository you cannot access the containter. Move this part into controller class and everything will be all right.